# sqlite delete not affecting database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, delete-record

In my app, I am trying to delete one record from an sqlite db. I use the following code in my DAO to delete. it is working with all other records expect specific one, I can't delete it eventhough the delete statement is executed successfully, I tried every thing but still can't figure out what special about this record (sqlite3_changes return 0 for this record while for others it returns 1 as expected). I am verifying it is not deleted by selecting from the table, I always find it there.

I tried to delete it from command line (sqlite on mac), still I can't delete it. Appreciate the help as I am really desperate here.

```
sqlite3_stmt *deleteVideoStmt = nil;
const char *sql = "delete from video where videoID = ?";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2([DBUtil db], sql, -1, &deleteVideoStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete video statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg([DBUtil db]));
sqlite3_bind_text(deleteVideoStmt, 1, [v.videoId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
double t = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
/*
if (sqlite3_exec([DBUtil db], "BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"couldn't begin transacton!!! %s",sqlite3_errmsg([DBUtil db]));
}
*/
int result = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if(SQLITE_DONE != result){
    NSLog(@"Error while executing video stmt. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg([DBUtil db]));
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return NO;
}else{
    NSLog(@"Update stmt executed successfully. in  %ld ms",lroundf(((CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-t)*1000)));
    /*
    if (sqlite3_exec([DBUtil db], "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't commit transacton!!! %s",sqlite3_errmsg([DBUtil db]));
    }
    */
    NSLog(@"number of rows affected = %d", sqlite3_changes([DBUtil db]));
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is an obvious question but it needs to be asked - are you sure there is a record with the `videID` you are binding in? What happens if you perform the same exact query from the command line?

Comment: What is the schema (`video`'s table definition)? (And you must the finalize the statement in both branches of the `if`.)

Comment: @rmaddy yes the video exist, actually I get it through a select a statement to the same table, then try to delete it with the same videoID but can't, I also tried to delete it from command line as I mentioned and it is not deleted although I don't get an error from the command line delete statement!!! very strange case, it is really annoying me, thanks for passing by anyway

Comment: @CL I don't the schema matters a lot as I am removing with one parameter in the where condition but here it is anyway!! for the finalize yes u r right, actually I added yesterday but still nothing changes (although I never got result not equal to SQLITE_DONE from the delete statement.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "video" ("albumName" TEXT, "artistName" TEXT, "author" TEXT, "categories" TEXT, "creationDate" DATETIME, "downloaded" BOOL, "downloadEndDate" DATETIME, "downloadProgress" DOUBLE, "downloadStartDate" DATETIME, "duration" DOUBLE, "fileSize" DOUBLE, "historyFlag" BOOL, "imgUrl" TEXT, "lastOpenedDate" DATETIME, "name" TEXT, "noOfViews" DOUBLE, "quality" INTEGER, "rating" DOUBLE, "relatedLink" TEXT, "songName" TEXT, "source" TEXT, "url" TEXT, "userRating" DOUBLE, "videoID" TEXT, "downloadStatus" INTEGER, "downloadHandler" INTEGER, "downloadFilePath" TEXT)

Comment: If you can't delete it from the command line then it isn't a problem with your code.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT videoID, typeof(videoID) FROM video WHERE ...` for this record?